# APEX: Can't add instances of a custom class as elements of a list within a complex class

Tags: apex, class, list

When I try to initialize an instance of the daisychain class below, using the makeDaisyChain method, I get a

> "System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object"
>   error.

```
   private class daisyChain {

        String name;
        List<offerRecipe> offers;   

    }

    private class offerRecipe {             // store offerRecipes in format ['name','householdID','targetPropertyID']

        String name;
        String householdID;
        String targetPropertyID;        
        String householdName;               // Attributes to make it easy to read offerRecipes without making additional DB calls
        String targetPropertyName;
        String isResident;

    }

    public static void makeDaisyChain() {

        offerRecipe firstOffer = new OfferRecipe();

        firstOffer.name = 'Justin\'s offer';
        firstOffer.householdID = '1234';
        firstOffer.targetPropertyID = '4567';
        firstOffer.targetPropertyName = 'Creek St';
        firstOffer.isResident = '(R)';

        system.debug(firstOffer);

        daisyChain thisDaisyChain = new daisyChain();
        thisDaisyChain.name = 'My Daisy Chain';
        thisDaisyChain.offers[0] = firstOffer;

    }
```

Problem seems to be with assigning firstOffer as the first offerRecipe in the offers list in the daisychain.

However, the debug log shows that firstOffer is not null

```
|DEBUG|offerRecipe:[householdID=1234, householdName=Philips, isResident=(R), 
name=Justin's offer, targetPropertyID=4567, targetPropertyName=Creek St]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the error that you should receive if you try to save such of class:

> Top level types must be public or global

And your method is out of your class so it needs to be within the class in order for you to access it.

**Try this:**

```
public class daisyChain {

        String name;
        List<offerRecipe> offers;   



    private class offerRecipe {  

        String name;
        String householdID;
        String targetPropertyID;        
        String householdName;     
        String targetPropertyName;
        String isResident;

    }

    public static void makeDaisyChain() {

        offerRecipe firstOffer = new OfferRecipe();

        firstOffer.name = 'Justin\'s offer';
        firstOffer.householdID = '1234';
        firstOffer.targetPropertyID = '4567';
        firstOffer.targetPropertyName = 'Creek St';
        firstOffer.isResident = '(R)';

        system.debug(firstOffer);

        daisyChain thisDaisyChain = new daisyChain();
        thisDaisyChain.name = 'My Daisy Chain';
        thisDaisyChain.offers[0] = firstOffer;

    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Carlos! The code was actually embedded inside another, public class. Extracting it from there, so my .apxc file has nothing but what you've got here unfortunately doesn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I needed to initialize the offers list.

```
private class daisyChain {

    String name = '';
    List<offerRecipe> offers = new List<offerRecipe>(); 

}
```

Without doing that, there was no list for thisDaisyChain.offers[0] to reference.